# KeyListener and KeyBinding issue

Tags: java, swing, keylistener

I have recently made a tank game, but I have been experiencing a serious issue. For keyboard input I used KeyListener, but in the process of playing, suddenly, the KeyListener wasn't responding. The keys just stopped working. I was looking for the issue on the internet and I found many answers saying that I should use KeyBinding. I did so, but the issue appeared again. What should I do?

This is just a small piece of code of the KeyBinding.

```
public Action redTankBackwardReleased = new AbstractAction("action") {
    private static final long serialVersionUID = 1L;
    public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e) {
        Game.redTank.xSpeed = 0;
        Game.redTank.ySpeed = 0;
    }
};

panel.getInputMap().put(KeyStroke.getKeyStroke("released DOWN"), "8");
panel.getActionMap().put("8", redTankBackwardReleased);
```

Everything works just perfect but after a few seconds or maybe a minute, the keys just stop responding... I do not understand.

Comment: If this is a Swing GUI, then Key Bindings *should* work, and if they don't, then you must have a bug in your code, one that we're not privy to. If you need help solving this here or on any site, you will want to post pertinent code. Best not to post the whole program or small snippets but rather a very small compilable and runnable program that demonstrates your problem, a [mcve].

Comment: without code there isn't much we can do. Best recommendation I can give is: a component only receives `KeyEvent`s if it has the focus, so just use a `FocusListener` to figure out when it looses focus. Apart from that there isn't much we can do without code.

Comment: @Paul: If he's using Key Bindings, then focus shouldn't be an issue ***if*** he uses the right InputMap, but again, we have no idea which InputMap he's using without his code.

Comment: @HovercraftFullOfEels well, that suggestion was rather about the `KeyListener`-part (should've made that clear). But in the end this whole thing is pretty pointless without any code anyways.

Comment: I am going to post here code in a second.

Comment: @Erninger well, the `serialVersionUID` shouldn't be set to `1L`, but apart from that there isn't much to tell from this piece of code. It's already been mentioned, but the code should be a [MCVE](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve), or in other words: the issue should be reproducible with the given code.

Comment: @Paul The entire game has 4 classes, all with 200 lines of code minimum, I do not know how to reproduce the code properly and shortly. Besides this, what should the serialVersionUID be set to? I also tried the FocusListener, and the focus is always on the JPanel, so it is not the problem.

Comment: I can paste the whole code here if you want.

Comment: @Erninger as for the `serialVersionUID`, the correct way would be to use [serialver](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/technotes/tools/windows/serialver.html) to generate it. As for the code: this is highly discouraged here, but I'll make an exception: just post (or add as a comment) a link to the files and I'll have a look.

Comment: @Paul here is the link - https://www.dropbox.com/sh/rkjp4pwu6n2885g/AAAKIDgD-8-_vFbEQGW9_ujsa?dl=0

Comment: @Erninger I took a look at the code. Works just fine for me, but you should try to code a lot cleaner. My first project looked pretty much like this and trust me, it'll break sooner or later and it'll be unfixable. And while I've got a nice decompiler, I wouldn't mind not to decompile and instead get code directly ;).

Comment: @Paul yes it looks like it is working, but try to move both of the tanks at the same time at least one minute. Then it will suddenly stop working. Yes, I know it is very messy and not clear, I am going to improve it.

Comment: @Erninger works just fine for me as well. This might be keyboard-related. Theres a limit on simultaneous keystrokes for most keyboards, which can be quite complicated (i.e. involve groupings of keys, types of keys, etc). I guess your keyboard simply doesn't support that many keypresses at once. I can quite fine move both tanks and even shoot simultaneously.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You're using the wrong InputMap. You should use the one associated with the int constant `JComponent.WHEN_IN_FOCUSED_WINDOW`. It should be something like

```
KeyStroke releasedDown = KeyStroke.getKeyStroke(KeyEvent.VK_DOWN, 0, true);
int condition = JComponent.WHEN_IN_FOCUSED_WINDOW;
InputMap inputMap = panel.getInputMap(condition);
ActionMap actionMap = panel.getActionMap(); // there's only one ActionMap

// then use as you normally would
inputMap.put(....);
actionMap.put(...);
```

Comment: If this doesn't solve your problem, then as noted in my comment to your question post a valid [mcve] -- please check out the link.

Comment: And where in this code should I implement the code that is going to run on the key pressed?

Comment: @Erninger: in the Action that goes into the ActionMap of course. Have you gone through the Key Bindings tutorial yet? If not please do so as it is well explained there: [Key Bindings](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/misc/keybinding.html)